# APACHE needs port 80 - MAMP

Tags: mamp

I want to run MAMP on my Windows 8.1 pc, but when I start the servers, it says:

```
'APACHE' needs open port '80' which is already being used by another 
service or application. Please reconfigure 'APACHE' to use free port.
```

Changing the port to something else doesn't help.

Comment: Run this command in cmd with Admin privileges. Be careful, it'll immediately kill any process running in Port 80. `FOR /F "tokens=5 delims= " %P IN ('netstat -a -n -o ^| findstr :80') DO TaskKill.exe /PID %P /T /F`

Answer (score 7):

when you have this problem just turn off Skype because Skype use port 80

Comment: turning off skype worked for me. I found a skype setting that I think will cause it to not use port 80: Tools > Options > Advanced > Connection
Uncheck "Use Port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections"

Answer (score 5):

I used kampageddon's answer and it worked. Just follow the following steps:

1. Run MAMP
2. Click Preferences
3. On Preference window click Ports
4. While on Ports change Apache & Nginx Port to 8080.
5. click ok
6. Start Servers.

Answer (score 2):

Start windows command line and then run
`netstat -aon | findstr :80`
You will see line with process that is using port 80

Comment: This didn't work, it's the comment to my question that worked

Answer (score 2):

I also found this post - https://superuser.com/questions/960023/port-80-already-in-use-after-windows-10-upgrade - suggesting disabling the IIS service, which worked perfectly for me

Comment: Not Excellent! what if I need the IIS beside of apache? Please check my answer: https://superuser.com/a/1788409/340522

Answer (score 1):

You can change MAMP ports in Preferences -> ports, like a screenshot below
[image: MAMP change port for using with Skype]

Answer (score 0):

Hey On Windows 10 I Ran into the same issue.. I found a way that is a guarantee fix... Go into controlpanel -> system security -> windows firewall -> on the left pane there is advanced settings.. click that. -> then add new inbound rule (on the left pane click inbound... then new rule on the right pane.) -> then follow the wizard as program and select mamp from C:/MAMP I believe. Then you are Golden!! Hope this helps all those out there with the new windows 10.
**Hypertextie**

Answer (score 0):

If you arrived here because you just installed MAMP on a Windows OS (7~10), then Microsoft IIS is the most likely culprit hanging on to port 80.

You can confirm that with the CLI netstat advice by [Sergio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30415455/5505243) below and should you find via netstat that a listening service has a process id that maps to NT Kernal & System (ntoskrnl.exe -> cross check via details tab in task manager) then the culprit is IIS.

To Turn off IIS;

Start menu -> Control Panel -> Programs & Features -> Turn Windows Features On or Off -> De-select 'Internet Information Services'.

If you know why IIS is running then you will likely know the application that specifically needs it and you can turn back on when need (take note of the selection chain when turning off) -- otherwise it's unlikely you need IIS on.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with recent windows update.  Closing skype did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Click Start > Settings > Ethernet >Network and Internet > Windows Firewall.
In the left pane, click Advanced Settings.
Find Local Port 80 with Protocol TCP. in my case is "World Wide Web Services (HTTP Traffic-In)"

check which program use this port 80
also you can know ip with port by running CMD as admin and write this line

netstat -aon | findstr "80"

and kill it by code:

taskill /F /PID 14276

14276 is the program code which use port 80

or
end task form services in task manager
restart Mamp again
enjoy!!!

Answer (score -1):

IN CASE YOU ALREADY TURNED SKYPE OFF AND THE ERROR STILL APPEARS, just try stopping the server and closing MAMP, then go to MAMP\db\mysql and delete the following files:

mysql-bin.index

ib_logfile0

ib_logfile1 files

The MySQL Server should now connect succesfully with the port 80!

Answer (score -2):

Thru some web searches, I discovered that other windows services are know to be using Port 80.
In Windows Search (via Windows Start), type 'services', stop one of these services below en test again till it works. Do not forget to restart it later !

- SQL Server Reporting Services
- Web Deployment Agent Service
- BranchCache
- Sync Share Service
- World Wide Web Publishing Service
- Internet Information Server