# MAMP how can I configure apache port to something other than 80

Tags: apache, mamp

Basically I am getting the error in this post: [APACHE needs port 80 - MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30415201/apache-needs-port-80-mamp) . The solution to original post is to kill the tasks using Port 80. But I don't want to kill the tasks which I don't know.

I have already changed the port number for Apache in MAMP UI. But I am still getting the same error message. Is there a way I can configure which port for Apache to use in MAMP?

Comment: There is really not enough information here, plus this is not programming related but rather server configuration stuff kind of question. Please ask this kind of question over at "Server Fault". Also please specify what OS you are using and what MAMP Version etc. I am sure there is tons of material from just doing a google search!

Comment: Do you have Skype? Skype can take over port 80.

Comment: @AlexBaban I don't use skype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Quit MAMP (make sure servers are stopped)
2. Open Apache configuration page `"c:\MAMP\conf\apache\httpd.conf"` (with a text editor)
3. Locate line `"Listen 80"`
4. Change to `"Listen 8080"`, save
5. Run MAMP UI (you should see the port for Apache changed to 8080)

Comment: Thank you for it. That works fine. But actually when I changed the settings in the GUI and quit MAMP. Then open the httpd.conf file, it is already updated with the new port. So I am guessing MAMP is loading from the .settings file just like windows cmd does. Loads every time itself opens