# I installed mamp but when I run it it gives an error: "'APACHE' needs open port '80' " and does not respond to clicks at all

Tags: mamp

I installed mamp but when I run it it gives an error: "'APACHE' needs open port '80' " and does not respond to clicks at all
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzQsn.jpg)

I tried googling how to fix this error, but I can't find anything

Comment: You should check what process using port 80 and terminate it. Maybe this: [How do I find out which process is listening on a TCP or UDP port on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-do-i-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-tcp-or-udp-port-on-windows). BTW Luuk's comment looks useful for me

Comment: I tried this way but the cmd gives out: 
"Error: Failed to complete process with process ID 364, child of process 4.
Reason: It's a critical system process. Taskkill cannot terminate it."

Comment: Probably another webservices is running on that port (like [IIS](https://www.iis.net/)).  You have two options 1) stop that webservices, of 2) Change the port number for apache in MAMP to, for example, 88. You should see MAMP (after APACHE starts) at http://localhost:88/

Comment: I will try to stop the service but is there a way to find out exactly what kind of service it is. And about the second option, I can not change the port, the fact that MAMP just does not respond to clicks, I can not even move the window

Comment: Normally you would do: `netstat -a -n -o -b | more` to see which process is using port 80, but it is not working well on Windows 11 

Comment: I finally fixed this error thanks to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37561623/mamp-how-can-i-configure-apache-port-to-something-other-than-80 and thank to everybody who tried to help me